# IIS 8.5 configuration on startup.cs (Azure webrole)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

    // Configure IIS to compress for requests coming through proxies (CDN).
    var httpCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpCompression");
    httpCompressionSection["noCompressionForHttp10"] = false;
    httpCompressionSection["noCompressionForProxies"] = false;
    httpCompressionSection["staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency"] = true;

    // Configure IIS threshold and time-period for compression
    var serverRuntimeSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/serverRuntime");
    serverRuntimeSection["frequentHitThreshold"] = 1;
    serverRuntimeSection["frequentHitTimePeriod"] = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0); // 1 day

    // Configure IIS to compress files beforehand
    var urlCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/urlCompression");
    urlCompressionSection["dynamicCompressionBeforeCache"] = true;

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

When I run this code locally, everything works as expected (locally means windows 10 + IIS express).
When I deploy this webrole to Azure, my machine (windows server 2012 R2 + IIS) crashes.

I can't debug this code on my deployed machine (not to my knowledge at least) so I'm trying to understand what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an error logging technology like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) to create a log for you of the error that is being thrown.

Try something similar to:

```
    try {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            // Configure IIS to compress for requests coming through proxies (CDN).
            var httpCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpCompression");
            httpCompressionSection["noCompressionForHttp10"] = false;
            httpCompressionSection["noCompressionForProxies"] = false;
            httpCompressionSection["staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency"] = true;

            // Configure IIS threshold and time-period for compression
            var serverRuntimeSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/serverRuntime");
            serverRuntimeSection["frequentHitThreshold"] = 1;
            serverRuntimeSection["frequentHitTimePeriod"] = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0); // 1 day

            // Configure IIS to compress files beforehand
            var urlCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/urlCompression");
            urlCompressionSection["dynamicCompressionBeforeCache"] = true;

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.ErrorFormat("Exception thrown during configuration! : {0}", e.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I see. So basically you don't find any problem with my code?

Comment: That I can't tell, but I can help you help yourself by adding logging which will help you debug the code. ;)